# Ajax Request with XMLHttpRequest: Different Format of HTTP Header "Accept-Language" with Internetexplorer

Tags: javascript, ajax, internet-explorer, http-headers

I have a problem with Internet Explorer 9. When I make an AJAX Request with a XMLHttpRequest object, the browser sends "de" for "Accept-Language" in the HTTP Header. When I am loading a page without AJAX the value for "Accept-Language" is "de-DE".

When using Firefox or Chrome in both cases the "Accept-Language" value is the same.

This difference causes trouble with some scripts I use on the page.

Is there any other way to fix this than manually setting the value with  xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Accept-Language","de-DE") ?

Comment: How would you know in JS that the browser attempted to send `de`? No, better adapt your scripts. Please show us how they rely on the accept-language

Answer (score 0):

The [language subtag is optional](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec3.html#sec3.10) so Internet Explorer is not at fault.

> Is there any other way to fix this than manually setting the value with `xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Accept-Language","de-DE")`?

The fix needs to be applied to the scripts that parse the header. The specifics of that will depend on how the scripts are written, not to the client. Don't try to control language preferences.